# Oracle count * and groupBy

Tags: sql, count, group-by

i ve the following oracle sentence that returns grouped results, for example 10 of one group, 8 of second group.

I am having trouble counting them, as it seems that this count(*) as stevilo_prosenj doesnt work properly, so i would appreciate if someone can help me how to get the result count of how many there are in each group..

Thank you

```
SELECT 
    PZB."OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID",
    PZB."VISOKOSOLSKO_SREDISCE_ID",
    leto.STUDIJSKO_LETO_ID,
    OBD.VRSTA_PROSNJE vrsta_prosnje_string,
    stdm.NAZIV_VRSTE_STUD_DOMOV naziv_vrste_stud_domov_ ,
    stdm.naziv naziv_stud_dom,
    SIFSTAT.OZNAKA OZNAKA_STATUSA_PROSNJE,
    count(*) as stevilo_prosenj


  FROM MSB_PROSNJE_ZA_BIVANJE PZB,
       S_OBD_POS_PRS_ZA_SUBV_VW OBD,
         S_VISOKOSOLSKO_SREDISCE_VW vss,
         S_STUDIJSKA_LETA_VW leto,
        S_STUDENTSKI_DOMOVI_VW stdm,
        MSB_SIF_STATUSOV_PROSENJ sifstat

  WHERE PZB.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID = OBD.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID
    AND vss.visokosolsko_sredisce_id     = pzb.visokosolsko_sredisce_id
    AND obd.studijsko_leto_id            = leto.studijsko_leto_id

GROUP BY
    PZB."OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID",
    PZB."VISOKOSOLSKO_SREDISCE_ID",
    leto.STUDIJSKO_LETO_ID,
    OBD.VRSTA_PROSNJE,
    stdm.NAZIV_VRSTE_STUD_DOMOV,
    stdm.naziv,
    SIFSTAT.OZNAKA
```

Comment: what do you mean, doesn't work properly?

Comment: Cartesian product is visible in your joins. Correct the same which might give you expected count

Comment: If you don't tell us what you have and what you expect, there's no way we can help you. I'm guessing you should try something like `COUNT(DISTINCT theFieldOnWhichYouWantToCount)`

Comment: As has been said, you have at least 2 cross joins in your query, if this is intended then ignore this, but if it isn't consider rewriting with ANSI-92 Explicit join syntax rather than the ANSI 89 syntax you are using. [There are some pretty good reasons to switch anyway](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins), but perhaps the best reason is that [the oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/queries006.htm#sthref2257) also recommend you switch.

Comment: The problem is i am a programmer (and not backend )and i have to take over a huge project, that also includes getting data from base and writting sql, but because everything is so huge and i dont have that much sql knowledge i thought that it is some easy solution.. Yes there are 2 joins, but i am not going to rewrite anything, gotta get lunch will talk some more later thanks for all the help for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you want a GROUP BY, but not on all of your SELECTed columns...

If your database supports it, you could

```
SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY columnA, columnB)
FROM table;
```

and otherwise, you'll have to select it manually

```
SELECT a.columnA, a.columnB, a.columnC, b.countResult
FROM (  SELECT columnA, columnB, columnC
        FROM table
        WHERE conditions
     ) a
JOIN
     (  SELECT columnA, columnB, count(*) AS countResult
        FROM table
        GROUP BY columnA, columnB
     ) b
ON a.columnA = b.columnA
AND a.columnB = b.columnB
/
```

Answer (score 0):

You join tables in your FROM statement but `S_STUDENTSKI_DOMOVI_VW stdm, MSB_SIF_STATUSOV_PROSENJ sifstat` tables aren't connected to others in the WHERE statement so they connect with all rows and you get FULL JOIN without conditions so COUNT outputs results you haven't expected (Multiplied to both tables row counts).

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to thank everyone for input and help, i ve fixed the problem since and i am just posting my solution, since i dislike leaving unanswered questions

Count part was giving me problems and i have solved it by doing this.

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSB_PROSNJE_ZA_BIVANJE pzb2 
WHERE PZB2.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID=pzb.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID
AND PZB2.MSB_STATUS=PZB.MSB_STATUS 
AND PZB2.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID=pzb.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID) stevilo
```

the whole sentence. So now i select everything and group, and i also make another select where i count as stevilo all those affected in the group. It works now.

```
SELECT pzb.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID,
pzb.MSB_STATUS,
pzb.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID,
OBD.OBDOBJE_PRIKAZ,
pzb.NAZIV_VRSTE_STUD_DOMOV,
PZB.OZNAKA_STATUSA_PROSNJE,
PZB.STUDIJSKO_LETO_ID,
PZB.STUDENTSKI_DOM_ID,
PZB.VISOKOSOLSKO_SREDISCE_ID,
PZB.NAZIV_VISOKOSOLSKEGA_SREDISCA NAZIV_V_SREDISCA,
PZB.NASLOV_VISOKOSOLSKEGA_SREDISCA NASLOV_V_SREDISCA,
PZB.NAZIV_STUD_DOM,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MSB_PROSNJE_ZA_BIVANJE pzb2 
WHERE PZB2.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID=pzb.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID
AND PZB2.MSB_STATUS=PZB.MSB_STATUS 
AND PZB2.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID=pzb.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID) stevilo 

FROM MSB_PROSNJE_ZA_BIVANJE_VW pzb,
S_OBD_POS_PRS_ZA_SUBV_VW obd

WHERE PZB.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID=OBD.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID 
GROUP BY  pzb.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID,
pzb.MSB_STATUS,
pzb.OBD_ZA_POSILJANJE_PROSENJ_ID,
OBD.OBDOBJE_PRIKAZ,
pzb.NAZIV_VRSTE_STUD_DOMOV,
PZB.OZNAKA_STATUSA_PROSNJE,
PZB.STUDIJSKO_LETO_ID,
PZB.VISOKOSOLSKO_SREDISCE_ID,
PZB.NAZIV_VISOKOSOLSKEGA_SREDISCA,
PZB.NASLOV_VISOKOSOLSKEGA_SREDISCA,
PZB.NAZIV_STUD_DOM,
PZB.STUDENTSKI_DOM_ID
ORDER BY pzb.VRSTA_STUD_DOMOV_ID
```